# How to add denominator count (Total sales) for stacked graphs in Tableau

Tags: graph, tableau-api

I have built a bar graph using tableau for the following data. How to add Total sales (120,150,200,180,140) on top of the each bar in tableau

```
   [The following image has the data and bar graph that I was trying to build]
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdA7s.png
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

I pivoted the data first to make it easier by working with a single measure.
Go to the data tab and select the `Sale A` and `Sale B` measures:

[image: measures selected]

Then hit the dropdown and select Pivot.

[image: pivot]

Then your data will look like this

[image]

Next, you want to set the fields up like this so it mirrors your screenshot.

[image: original]

The `SUM(Pivot Field Values)` is a table calculation set up as `percent of total` calculated `Table (down)`.

[image]

Then just duplicate your measure by holding `Ctrl` and dragging to `Rows`. Make it a label in the `Marks` section. This will add the total. You just have to play with the axis and format to get it into the place you want from here.

[image: ,]